# issue related to changing matform field based on the condition

Tags: angular

I have a form where iam showing the dropdown with values[users,receipts, companies, reviewer].based on the roles i need to show the values. for eg: if the role is admin , i will show only the users, receipts and companies. if the role is reviewer , i will show only the reviewer, if the role is superadmin i will show only the user.i tried using the mat option with if condition. it is working fine for the super admin and admin, but the issue is for reviewer also it showing the same values.
i tried changing the form field based on the if condition ,but its not working,. can anyone tell how to achieve that thing.

```
HTML
-------------
  <mat-form-field  *ngIf="(helperSrv.getRoles()=='role_super_admin'|| helperSrv.getRoles()!=='role_super_admin')&&(helperSrv.getRoles()!=='Reviewer')">
        <mat-label>Search By*</mat-label>
        <mat-select class="form-control" formControlName="type" id="type">
          <ng-container *ngFor="let type of searchDataSrv.searchType ">
            <mat-option *ngIf="type.value=='users' && helperSrv.getRoles()=='role_super_admin'" [value]="type.value">
              {{type.viewValue}}
            </mat-option>
            <mat-option  *ngIf="helperSrv.getRoles()!='role_super_admin'" [value]="type.value">
              {{type.viewValue}}
            </mat-option>
          </ng-container>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>


 public searchType = [
    { value: 'users', viewValue: 'Users' },
    { value: 'receipts', viewValue: 'Receipts' },
    { value: 'storages', viewValue: 'Storages' },
    {value:'reviewer',viewValue:'Reviewer'}
  ];
the if condition which i used in matform field is not working.it is howing this form field in the reviewer also.[![if it is reviewer i need to show only the reviewer][1]][1]
```

Comment: what is returned by helperSrv.getRoles()?

Comment: @Tejeshree, helperSrv.getRoles() , will return  the roles of the user. eg: if im in logged in with superadmin username ,the role return the superadmin.,if i logged in with reviewer ,it return the reviewer.

Comment: @manigandan: when you say "its not working" , what is happening ?  are you getting console error ? it would be better if you can create a demo code on https://stackblitz.com/

Answer (score 0):

Create a pipe for filtering item based on role

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'myfilter',
    pure: false
})
export class MyFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any[], role: string): any {

      if(role === 'admin'){
       return  ['users','receipts', 'companies']
      }
      else if(role === 'reviewer'){
          return ['reviewer']
      }
      else {
          return  ['users','receipts', 'companies', 'reviewer'];
      }
        
    }
}
```

Pass the role to that filter

```
<form>

  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Roles</mat-label>
    <select matNativeControl [(ngModel)]="selectedRole" name="car">
      <option value="" selected></option>
      <option *ngFor="let role of roles" [value]="role">
        {{role}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </mat-form-field>
  <p> Selected Role: {{selectedRole}} </p>

  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>types</mat-label>
    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" name="food">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let type of userTypes | myfilter : selectedRole" [value]="type">
        {{type}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>


  <p> Selected type {{selectedValue}} </p>

 
</form>
```